# Recommended way to remove events on destroy with jQuery UI Widget Factory

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-widget-factory

I'm using the jQuery UI Widget Factory to build a jQuery plugin.

My plugin binds custom events to the window...

```
_subscribe: function() {
  $(window).on("dragger.started", function() { ... });
}
```

I am wondering how to go about removing these events, when a particular instance of the plugin is destroyed.  If I use...

```
destroy: function() {
  $(window).off("dragger.started");
}
```

...then that will mess up any other instances of the plugin on the page, as it will remove all "dragger.started" events.

What is the recommended way to go about destroying only those events that are associated with an instance of the plugin?

Thanks (in advance) for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind multiple namespaces in an event.  So assign your instance an id like

```
//this.id = 'dragger_' + guid_or_static_count
$(window).on("dragger.started." + this.id, function() { ... });
```

And later

```
$(window).off('dragger.' + this.id);
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U89tw/2/)

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to get rid of the instance? jQuery remove() will remove bound events, I believe.

Comment: thanks for your response.  This is if I want to destroy the changes made by the plugin, without removing the original element from the DOM -- similar to the way the jQuery UI plugins work.  eg $("#myDiv").myPlugin("destroy");

Comment: Like you want to reset to the original state, as in x/y coordinates or some such? To do that I'd think you'd need to save the original state somewhere first, like in a JavaScript variable, then just use those settings to set the attribute or property or css or whatever you were changing when you want to reset, right?