# Remove event handler for one instance of jQuery widget

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I've written a widget using the jQuery UI widget factory (in Typescript).

My widget listens for scroll events on the window element, so an event handler is added in the `_create` function:

```
_create = function () {
   $(window).on("scroll", this.handleScroll);
}
```

And in the `_destroy` function I want to remove the handler:

```
_destroy = function () {
   $(window).off("scroll", this.handleScroll);
}
```

However, there can be two instances of this widget on my page: one in the regular page, and one in a popup. My current implementation removes the handlers for both instances, which is clearly unwanted.

I've read this question: [Recommended way to remove events on destroy with jQuery UI Widget Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13907368/recommended-way-to-remove-events-on-destroy-with-jquery-ui-widget-factory), the accepted answer there works fine for a custom event, but I cannot see a solution for a standard event like `scroll`.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: See my answer below. If it works for you, you should accept so that this answer doesn't show up in the question stream of users logging in now. If it doesn't or if you need any clarifications, leave me a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That solution will work for you too. If you don't have them already, assign ids to both your widgets - on the page and in the pop-up. Then, modify your code like this:

```
_create = function () {
   $(window).on("scroll." + this.id, this.handleScroll);
}

_destroy = function () {
   $(window).off("scroll." + this.id, this.handleScroll);
}
```

Please notice the "." after the scroll in the calls to on() and off(). See this article: [Namespaced events in jquery](http://css-tricks.com/namespaced-events-jquery/) and [this one](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201205/safer_event_handling_with_jquery_namespaced_events/).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize this worked for standard events as well. I made this the accepted answer, as your seems to be the first one seconds before roydukkey's answer :)

Comment: Namespacing events is fantastic for complex apps with dynamic content. I used this for when tags were being added and removed in a selectize widget and I didn't have a function reference to remove the handler after removing the tag. This prevented memory leak issues. I never knew about namespacing events in jquery before. Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

The answer you refer should work in your case as well. You could try something like this.

```
_create = function () {
   $(window).on("scroll." + this.id, this.handleScroll);
}

$(window).off('scroll.' + this.id);
```